# One domain using old version of PHP while other domain is using new

Tags: php, dedicated

Community,

I have a dedicated server that is using PLESK 9.

I while ago I SSH'd to the server and updated PHP to 5.4.  Today I added a new domain to the server and for some reason phpinfo() is reporting that it is using 5.1.

My other domains are confirmed to be using 5.4.  Any idea why this is happening?

Kindest Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Plesk for ages but;

1 - Check the hosting properties. Change the PHP version if Plesk let you.

2 - Check the virtual host configs over SSH and compare the configs of those domains.

One of these steps should solve your problem.

Comment: I can't select which version of PHP I can use via PLESK.  How can I check the vhost config?  I appreciate your answer.

Comment: If I remember right and plesk didn't change it, it should be located under /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf

Comment: There is a file called httpd.include, I am not sure what I am looking for in the file.  There is nothing regarding what PHP binary it is using.

Comment: Sorry Dan but I don't remember that much. Still, you can look for Apache's LoadModule directive. I am not sure how can I help more without seeing any config. By the way, you check the DNS records right ? You're sure that the domains are hosted by the same server ?